# analysis group not visible

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to do some regression. However I have no Data Analysis group in the Data tab.

I've been through the sequence File/Options/Add-Ins and the Analysis ToolPak is in the upper group "Active Application". I've tried highlighting it again and clicking Go.. to get the dialogue box where "Analysis Toolpak" and "Analysis Toolpak - VBA" and "Solver Add-In" are all ticked, then OK, but still my Data ribbon only shows 5 groups (Get External Data, Connections, Sort&Filter, Data Tools and Outline) - no "Analysis" which I expect to find from reading various instruction threads on the net.

Can anyone suggest what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

- Go to File >Options > Add-ins > in the bottom click **GO**
- Check: **Analysis Toolpak**, **Analysis Toolpak-VBA** and **Solver** should be checked as available

If this doesn't work, then in **File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings-> Add-ins** check the first checkbox.

[image]

Then, it should appear under <kbd>Data</kbd> tab:
[image]

- If not, Restart excel. Also, after then, uncheck "**Solver**" plugin from options again, only "**Data Analysis**" will be left.

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this.
Yes, these three add-ins are ticked
My trust centre settings are as shown
Still no data analysis group.
Any other suggestions please?
Stuart

Comment: Drat, after a reboot is has appeared (called "analysis" not "data analysis" Thanks for your help

Comment: If you register your Super User account with the same OpenID as you used for your Stack Overflow account you'll regain ownership of the question and be able to comment on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Forced Excel process to close, then re-opened.
Analysis Group appeared.

Answer (score 0):

I has success finding this icon by re-installing the add-in.

1. Starting with the dialog in Excel (v. 2013): File -> Options -> Add-ins -> "Manage" -> (dropdown) "Excel Add-ins" -> "Go..."
2. Deselect the Solver package check box (if previously installed), confirm by pressing ok
3. Return to the dialog above and select Solver package, click OK to confirm and to begin the re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Found this to work:**

File->Addins-> "Manage: ((*selection*))"

Unactivate "Analysis ToolPak" (*Excel Add-ins*)
[Check box, click "OK"]

Reactivate "Analysis ToolPak" (*Excel Add-ins*)
[Check box, click "OK"]

**If still not showing:**

Then do the Activation or Un/Re-activation Sequence for "Analysis" (*COM Add-in*)
[Check box, click "OK"]